# XPath Boolean Expression Always Returns True

Tags: java, xpath

I am evaluating the below XPath Boolean expression using Java's XPath API. However, the expression always returns true.

**boolean(//InteractionControl/MessageId[text() = "fdsfsd"])**

The text value of the **MessageId** node in the XML document is "9000," so the above XPath expression should return false unless I am missing something.

Comment: If `count(//InteractionControl/MessageId[text() = "fdsfsd"])` is not 0, than your xpath matches non-empty Node set

Comment: @IvanPronin That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, thanks, added the answer

Comment: How many MessageId elements are in your document? It would be helpful if you posted an example XML document that is producing the unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

If `count(//InteractionControl/MessageId[text() = "fdsfsd"])` is not 0, than your xpath matches non-empty Node set, which resolves `boolean()` function to true. See here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/boolean

Comment: Much better. Avoid the temptation to provide complete, accurate answers in comments :-)

Comment: I tried two different count XPATH expressions, and both of them returned a value of 48.

count(InteractionControl/MessageId[text() = "5050"])

count(/InteractionControl/MessageId[text() = "392493294-394329432"])

However, there is nowhere they would actually match in the XML document I am evaluating. Could it be an issue with Java's XPATH API?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by using the "evaluate" function in the XPath API which takes an argument specifying a return type.

```
Boolean evaluation = xPath.compile(xPathStr).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN)
```

Maybe the "evaluate" function that does not take an argument specifying the return type has a bug.

Comment: Without the second argument, evaluate() is supposed to convert the result to a string, which should be either "true" or "false".